# How should the Master Detail tables estructure be?

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms

I want to register some Overtime into the database. I have two tables.. I want the user to be able to add the hours several at a time for each emplyee. This would mean they have one ID for several inputs.
I am wondering what my structure would be, I have a table that holds the ID, EMPLOYEE, DATE, NUMBER OF HOURS and another one that holds ID, EMPLOYEE, DATE_REGISTRATION, NO_EMPL_BOSS, NO_EMPL_SUB.

I am hoping to create an ID with some basic information and then add each registry of over time for that same employee (could be a few all throughout a month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table Employees(
id int not null primary key identity,
name nvarchar(200),
registrationDate datetime
);

create table Employees_overtime(
id int not null primary key identity,
employee_id int not null,
creationDate datetime,
overtime float not null,
constraint fk_employees_overtime foreign key(employee_id) references Employees(id)
);
```

I guess you mean something like this